# what the correct synatax to use XMLFormat() in Coldfusion with input fields?

Tags: xml, coldfusion, input, coldfusion-8

I'm sitting on a from trying the Coldfuion XMLFormat() function.

However if I do this:

```
<form name="sample" action="#cgi.script_name#" method="post">
    <input name="test" value="#XMLFormat( form.test )#" type="text" tabindex="1" />
</form>
```

I'm just getting CF-erors, that element *test* is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if `form.test` exists:

```
<form name="sample" action="#cgi.script_name#" method="post">
  <input name="test" value="<CFIF structkeyexists(form,"test")>#XMLFormat( form.test )#</CFIF>" type="text" tabindex="1" />
</form>
```

Comment: doesn't like the if-else shorthand - Invalid token ? found... trying CFIF

Comment: in CF8 I have to <cfif></cfif>, correct? So I'm getting no error with <input name="test" <cfif structkeyexists(form,"sample")>value="#XMLFormat( form.test)#"</cfif> type="text" />

Comment: Ok. Need to fiddle with some more, because I have 3 forms on my page. But more or less works. Thanks again!

Comment: Good answers but you (Depending on your logic) you might try just adding some <cfparam> tags above your form as in <cfparam name="form.test" value=""/>  (or value= some default value).

Comment: @MarkAKruger - I think that just might be it...because all my tests with structkeyexists or isdefined just fail. Is this because I need to "setup" the form fields first, because the form scope will only be available once the form is submitted... (did I get this right...?)

Comment: No ... you can test for the existence of a Form variable as well - using isDefined() or StructKeyExist() as in the example that Seybsen gave. If you are getting an error it's probably not done right (sorry:).  but predefining them works too and is a good idea if you want some defaults to work with.